# INSERT INTO View Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a view created by referring to two synonyms. The current query I've to harvest my View Table is as below

```
SELECT  dbo.synonym1.JobNo
      , dbo.synonym1.Customer
      , dbo.synonym2.PostalService
      , dbo.synonym2.FirstDate
      , dbo.synonym2.SecondDate
FROM dbo.synonym1 
  INNER JOIN dbo.synonym2 ON dbo.synonym1.JobNo = sbo.synonym2.JobNo
WHERE dbo.synonym2.PostalService = 'UPS'
```

Now I would like to find the difference between `dbo.synonym2.FirstDate` and `dbo.synonym2.SecondDate` in each row and `INSERT` the same row again into the View Table as many times as there is a difference.

For example if the `FirstDate` is `2012-06-03 00:00:00.000` and `SecondDate` is `2012-06-05 00:00:00.000` then it should insert the same row twice.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm a newbie to SQL. Please help me out

Sample data that gets populated currently with the above query in the view is as below,

```
JobNo  Customer PostalService FirstDate                 SecondDate  
1      ABC      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-03 00:00:00.000
2      DEF      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-06 00:00:00.000
3      XYZ      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-05 00:00:00.000
```

I would need a result as below

```
JobNo  Customer PostalService FirstDate                 SecondDate  
1      ABC      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-03 00:00:00.000
2      DEF      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-05 00:00:00.000
2      DEF      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-05 00:00:00.000
2      XYZ      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-05 00:00:00.000
3      XYZ      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-06 00:00:00.000
3      XYZ      UPS           2012-06-03 00:00:00.000   2012-06-06 00:00:00.000
```

If you see the difference between the dates for JobNo 2 is 3 so data is repeated three times. and for the JobNo 3 is 2 so data is repeated twice.

Comment: You don't insert into a view, and I'm not sure what a "View Table" is. Can you show some sample data and desired results, instead of saying how you want to accomplish them? I am sure there is a better way than what you are describing. If you're running a query (the primary use for a view), there shouldn't be any need for inserting anything.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to explain it clearly. I've updated the question with sample data as you requested. Also when I mentioned View Table, it just means View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a little confusing, because one doesn't generally insert into views.

However, the following will insert rows into a table

```
insert into ViewTable(JobNo, Customer, PostalService, FirstDate, SecondDate)
    SELECT dbo.synonym1.JobNo, dbo.synonym1.Customer, dbo.synonym2.PostalService,
           dbo.synonym2.FirstDate, dbo.synonym2.SecondDate
     FROM dbo.synonym1 INNER JOIN
          dbo.synonym2
          ON dbo.synonym1.JobNo = sbo.synonym2.JobNo
     WHERE dbo.synonym2.PostalService = 'UPS' and
           datediff(d, FirstDate, SecondDate) <> 0
```

You need to define ViewTable as an actual table though.

Comment: I'm sorry for being confusing. I'm new to this. When I tried your query, it just gives me the data that has date difference.

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new record for each date in the range?  If so, you should update your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like what you want is the union statement below to populate this temp table.
unless i am misunderstanding what you are asking for.

```
DECLARE @MyTable as TABLE(JobNo VARHCAR(50), Customer VARCHAR(50), 
                       Postalservice VARCHAR(50), MyDate DateTime)

INSERT into @MyTable 
SELECT  dbo.synonym1.JobNo 
  , dbo.synonym1.Customer 
  , dbo.synonym2.PostalService 
  , dbo.synonym2.FirstDate 

FROM dbo.synonym1  
INNER JOIN dbo.synonym2 ON dbo.synonym1.JobNo = sbo.synonym2.JobNo 
WHERE dbo.synonym2.PostalService = 'UPS'  
UNION
SELECT  dbo.synonym1.JobNo 
  , dbo.synonym1.Customer 
  , dbo.synonym2.PostalService 

  , dbo.synonym2.SecondDate 
FROM dbo.synonym1  
INNER JOIN dbo.synonym2 ON dbo.synonym1.JobNo = sbo.synonym2.JobNo 
WHERE dbo.synonym2.PostalService = 'UPS'
```

INSERT into your view from @MyTable

Comment: Are you sure that you want to describe that as "INSERT into your view"?

Comment: I'm sorry. Im not looking for a UNION. I updated my question. Please take a look once more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #temp
(
    StartDate DateTime,
    EndDate DateTime
)

Insert into #temp(StartDate, EndDate)
                    Values('2012-06-03 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-03 00:00:00.000');
Insert into #temp(StartDate, EndDate)
                    Values('2012-06-03 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-06 00:00:00.000');
Insert into #temp(StartDate, EndDate)
                    Values('2012-06-03 00:00:00.000', '2012-06-05 00:00:00.000');

With DateRange As
(
    select Convert(DateTime, '2012-06-02 00:00:00.000') as StartDate, 
          DATEADD(dd, 1, Convert(DateTime, '2012-06-02 00:00:00.000')) as EndDate
    Union All
    select EndDate, DATEADD(dd, 1, EndDate) From DateRange 
                    Where EndDate <= Convert(DateTime, '2012-06-10 00:00:00.000')
)

Select T.* from #temp T
Left Join DateRange R on ((T.StartDate < R.EndDate and T.EndDate > R.StartDate) 
          or (T.StartDate = R.EndDate and T.EndDate = R.StartDate))
order  by T.EndDate

Drop table #temp
```

Comment: I won't be always not knowing the Date Range. So I'm not sure if this can be used. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1345260 That value can be calculated like this. `Select Min(StartDate) From YourTable`

Comment: @user1345260 and `Select Max(StartDate) From YourTable`